# VBA hiding multiple textboxes using for loop

Tags: vba, variables, excel, for-loop

I have a VBA form in excel with multiple textboxes, called tboTEXT1, tboTEXT2, and so on to tboTEXT20. I also have a textbox tboNumber, when I enter a number from 1 to 20, that amount of tboTEXT textboxes should be visible. So I use tboNumber_Change(). On every number entered first a tboTEXT textboxes should be made invisible and subsequently made visible depending on the number entered in tboNumber.
Problem: I want to use a For loop through the tboTEXTi textboxes with i = 1 to 20 instead if 20 times tboTEXTi.visible = false.
Whatever I used so far, I always get an error, stuff lke "object required"...

```
Private Sub tboNumber_Change()
For i = 1 To 20
varTEXT = "formFORM.tboTEXT" & i
varTEXT.Visible = False
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
VarTEXT = "formFORM.tboTEXT" & i
```

With:

```
Set VarTEXT = formFORM.Controls("tboTEXT" & i)
```

In this way you will correctly reference the textbox object. Otherwise your varTEXT will be no more than a string.

Comment: You'll need to use `Set` to pass Object on `VarTEXT` variable.